# MagicalRecord import of polymorphic relationship

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I using MagicalRecord to import data into a CoreData Model that makes heavy use of polymorphism.

For example, a set of concrete entities all extending the same abstract entity, are used in a many-to-many relationship from another class, which has it's property type specified in the model as being of the Abstract class type, allowing the Set to be be a mixture of both concrete types.

MagicalRecord does not generate the correct sub entities from the imported data.

Here is an example of the *simplest* case.

I have an entity called `PlantName` which has a `names` Set defined as type `NameComponent`.
I have an Abstract Entity `NameComponent` which has: `searchString`, `timeStamp` and `title`.
It is extended by two sub entities : `CommonName` which has `locale` and `LatinName` which has `type`.

The relevant snippet of JSON to be imported :

```
"names": [                                        /* NameComponent(s) */
    {"title": "Jade Plant", "locale": "en_us"},   /* CommonName - US English */
    {"title": "Crassulaceae", "type":4},          /* LatinName - Family */
    {"title": "Crassula", "type":5},              /* LatinName - Genus */
    {"title": "Ovata", "type":6}                  /* LatinName - Species */
]
```

After the import runs, if I look in the SQLite DB, I find all of the records have been imported as the abstract class type, furthermore, all of the attributes unique to each concrete class type are missing.

The only place where I can find an example of this working is in the Unit Tests for MagicalRecord. However, even that is different in one important place. The test relationships are concretely typed, whereas mine are typed by the abstract class.

I assume this difference is what is causing MagicalRecord to not generate the individual records as concrete classes.

Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for a way to implement polymorphism with Magical Record. I'm not sure my answer will help for this particular question (especially since its 18months late :)), but it should in general for anyone who lends here like I did.

Assuming you have something like that (using Rails):

```
class Event
  has_one :location, :as => :localizable, :dependent => :destroy
end

class User
  has_one :location, :as => :localizable, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Location
  belongs_to :localizable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

And your location json looks like:

```
{
  id: 1,
  localizable_id: 1,
  localizable_type: "Event"
}
```

Your Location.m in Xcode can look like that:

```
@interface Location ()

@end


@implementation Location {
    NSString *_localizableType;
}

- (void) willImport:(id)data {
    _localizableType = [data valueForKey:@"localizable_type"];
}

- (BOOL) shouldImportEvent:(id)data;
{

    return [_attachableType isEqualToString:@"Event"];
}

- (BOOL) shouldImportUser:(id)data;
{

    return [_attachableType isEqualToString:@"User"];
}

@end
```

Don't forget to set mappedKeyName to "localizable_id" in your data model user infos for each relation.

See [Importing Data Made Easy](http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/) or browse the source code to learn about the willImport: and shouldImport: callbacks and how to set mappedKeyName.

**The logic behind this:**

data for shouldImport: is just the id, we can't access localizable_type from there, so we just set a private attribute (_localizable_type) beforehand, and use it during the import.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case I hadn't considered when I wrote the MagicalImport library. I'll have to add this as a future update.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I look forward to using the feature :-)

Comment: Just ran into this issue myself - have there been any updates? Otherwise, I will have to write the support for polymorphic relationships.

Comment: If you do, be sure to submit a pull request.